# Getting "java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()" in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Image of DB in firebase console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdPWE.png)

I don't really know what's wrong here, I am able to add data on the other activity. I am getting error "java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()" and don't know how to fix. There are 3 other classes created only one other is adding data to firebase realtime database storage.

```
package com.example.akshay.katiroll.FirstScreen;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.akshay.katiroll.R;
import com.example.akshay.katiroll.SecondScreen.welcome;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText fName, lName, PhNo, BDay, Zip;
    Button svBtn;
    DatabaseReference mDataReference;
    String keyUser;
    String fNameStr, lNameStr, PhNoStr, BDayStr, ZipStr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        keyUser = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_KEY");
        mDataReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(keyUser);//error in this line
        fName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fName); 
        lName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lName);
        PhNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phno);
        BDay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bday);
        Zip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.zip);
        svBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.svBtn);
        svBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                fNameStr = fName.getText().toString();
                lNameStr = lName.getText().toString();
                PhNoStr = PhNo.getText().toString();
                BDayStr = BDay.getText().toString();
                ZipStr = Zip.getText().toString();

                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(fNameStr) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(lNameStr) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(PhNoStr)) {
                    DatabaseReference mDataRef = mDataReference.child("Users").push();
                    mDataRef.child("firstName").setValue(""+fNameStr);
                    mDataRef.child("lastName").setValue(""+lNameStr);
                    mDataRef.child("phoneNumber").setValue(""+PhNoStr);
                    mDataRef.child("isVerified").setValue("verified");
                    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(BDayStr)){
                        mDataRef.child("birthday").setValue(""+BDayStr);
                    }else{ 
                        mDataRef.child("birthday").setValue("null");
                    }
                    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(ZipStr)){
                        mDataRef.child("zipcode").setValue("ZipStr");
                    }else{
                        mDataRef.child("zipcode").setValue("null");
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "User profile added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    startActivity(new Intent(Profile.this, welcome.class));

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Failed to create User Account", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        });
    }
}





package com.example.akshay.katiroll.FirstScreen;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.example.akshay.katiroll.R;
import com.example.akshay.katiroll.SecondScreen.welcome;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.Iterator;


public class katiRoll extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText userEdit;
    EditText passEdit;
    String sUser, sPass;
    Button sign;
    Button reg;
    Boolean signInVLogIn;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kati_roll);
        float Re = 255;
        float Gr = 148;
        float Bl = 0;
        userEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user);
        passEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
        sign = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign);
        reg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reg);
        userEdit.setTextColor(Color.rgb(Re,Gr,Bl));
        passEdit.setTextColor(Color.rgb(Re,Gr,Bl));
        sign.setTextColor(Color.rgb(Re,Gr,Bl));
        reg.setTextColor(Color.rgb(Re,Gr,Bl));
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(sUser) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(sPass)){
                    signInVLogIn = true;
                }else{
                    signInVLogIn = false;
                }
                if(user != null && signInVLogIn) {

                }else{
                    //Toast.makeText(katiRoll.this, "Log In Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };
        sign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sUser = userEdit.getText().toString().trim();
                sPass = passEdit.getText().toString().trim();

                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(sUser) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(sPass))
                {

                    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(sUser, sPass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                                        checkUserValidation(dataSnapshot, sUser);

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                    }
                                });
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(katiRoll.this, "User Login Doesn't Exist" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(katiRoll.this, signUp.class));
            }
        });

    }

    private void checkUserValidation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String emailForVer) {
               Iterator iterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {

            DataSnapshot dataUser = (DataSnapshot)iterator.next();

            if (dataUser.child("emailUser").getValue().toString().equals(emailForVer)){
                if(dataUser.child("isVerified").getValue().toString().equals("unverified"))
                {
                    Intent in = new Intent(katiRoll.this, Profile.class);
                    in.putExtra("USER KEY", dataUser.child("userKey").getValue().toString());
                    startActivity(in);
                    Log.d("USERKEY",dataUser.child("userKey").getValue().toString());
                }
                else{
                    startActivity(new Intent(katiRoll.this, welcome.class));
                }
            }

        }



    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(mAuthListener !=null){
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }

}

package com.example.akshay.katiroll.FirstScreen;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.akshay.katiroll.SecondScreen.welcome;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import com.example.akshay.katiroll.R;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class signUp extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText nUser, nPass;
    Button registerBtn, backToMain;
    ImageButton passVis;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef, mUserCheckData;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
        nUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nUser);
        nPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nPass);
        registerBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerBtn);
        backToMain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backToMain);
        passVis = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.passVis);
        passVis.setImageResource(R.drawable.open);
        passVis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Drawable drawable = passVis.getDrawable();
                if(drawable.getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.open,null).getConstantState())){
                    passVis.setImageResource(R.drawable.closed);
                    nPass.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);

                }else{
                    passVis.setImageResource(R.drawable.open);
                    nPass.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_PASSWORD);
                }
            }
        });
        float Re = 255;
        float Gr = 148;
        float Bl = 0;
        nUser.setTextColor(Color.rgb(Re, Gr, Bl));
        nPass.setTextColor(Color.rgb(Re, Gr, Bl));
        registerBtn.setTextColor(Color.rgb(Re, Gr, Bl));
        backToMain.setTextColor(Color.rgb(Re, Gr, Bl));
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mUserCheckData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User");
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    final String emailForVer = user.getEmail();
                    mUserCheckData.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            checkForValidation(dataSnapshot, emailForVer);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }

            }
        };
        registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final String nUserString, nPassString;
                nUserString = (nUser.getText().toString().trim());
                nPassString = (nPass.getText().toString().trim());
                if(nPassString.length()>=6){
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(nUserString) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(nPassString)) {

                        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(nUserString, nPassString).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    DatabaseReference mChildDatabase = mDatabaseRef.child("Users").push();
                                    String key_user = mChildDatabase.getKey();
                                    mChildDatabase.child("isVerified").setValue("unverified");
                                    mChildDatabase.child("userKey").setValue(key_user);
                                    mChildDatabase.child("EmailUser").setValue(nUserString);
                                    mChildDatabase.child("PasswordUser").setValue(nPassString);
                                    Toast.makeText(signUp.this, "User Account Created, Check Email For Confirmation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                    if (user != null) {
                                        user.sendEmailVerification();
                                    }

                                    startActivity(new Intent(signUp.this, Profile.class));

                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(signUp.this, "Failed to create User Account", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(signUp.this, "Failed to create User Account", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(signUp.this, "Failed to create User Account", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        backToMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(signUp.this, katiRoll.class));
            }
        });


    }

    private void checkForValidation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String emailForVer) {
        Iterator iterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {

            DataSnapshot dataUser = (DataSnapshot)iterator.next();

            if (dataUser.child("emailUser").getValue().toString().equals(emailForVer)){
                if(dataUser.child("isVerified").getValue().toString().equals("unverified"))
                {
                    Intent in = new Intent(signUp.this, Profile.class);
                    in.putExtra("USER KEY", dataUser.child("userKey").getValue().toString());
                    startActivity(in);
                    Log.d("USERKEY",dataUser.child("userKey").getValue().toString());

                }
                else{
                    startActivity(new Intent(signUp.this, welcome.class));
                }
            }

        }



    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(mAuthListener !=null){
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }
}

package com.example.akshay.katiroll.SecondScreen;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.example.akshay.katiroll.FirstScreen.katiRoll;
import com.example.akshay.katiroll.R;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class welcome extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button logOutBtn;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
        float Re = 255;
        float Gr = 148;
        float Bl = 0;
        logOutBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.logOutBtn);
        logOutBtn.setTextColor(Color.rgb(Re,Gr,Bl));
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if(user !=null) {


                }else{



                }
            }
        };
        logOutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mAuth.signOut();
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(welcome.this, katiRoll.class));
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please post your database structure? or a photo of it ?

Comment: `keyUser` is`null`

Comment: post where you are doing putExtra("USER_KEY");

Comment: i just did, in both the katiRoll.java and signUp.java files, at the bottom of them

Comment: the problem is in your getExtras, just do a simple Log.e("NullCheck",""+keyUser); and check when it throw the error if that is null, if that value is null is because you are puting that value wrong at your checkForValidation() method, or you are getting it wrong at Profile.class, check my answer below, it might help !

Comment: I added log statements in the iterators and nothing is showing up as if they are not even running. Furthermore, when I click register in my signup class, the application crashes with the error java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.akshay.katiroll/com.example.akshay.katiroll.FirstScreen.Profile}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()

Comment: therefore, running the NullCheck is not showing up because the profile class never runs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67449449/4828650

Answer (score 1):

The problem that is telling to you is that you are doing wrong the reference, you are trying to get something inside `Firebase Database` that is not there

This line is telling you that the `child("Users").child(KeyUser);` does not exist in your current DB structure

To fix this you should see your databse structure and then redo your reference.

if you post a photo of your Firebase DB i will be glad to refactor your code to your needs.

also here you are getting wrong your `USER_KEY`

```
keyUser = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_KEY");
```

To fix this a short way would be doing this

```
 keyUser = getIntent().getExtras().getString("USER_KEY");
```

you are geting an intent from where? if you are trying to get a putExtra from another Activity, you are doing it wrong, post where you are seting the extra `("USER_KEY");`

`Intent.getStringExtra()` and `Intent.getExtras()` returns null if there are no extras, so you need to check for that before trying to call `getString()`

one quick example to check for extras first would be this

```
String keyUser;
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras == null) {
    Log.e("keyUser is null","");
} else {
    keyUser= extras.getString("USER_KEY");
}
```

happy coding

Comment: I think I understand but just so I am crystal clear, the issue is that my userkey intent is not being sent properly from the prior activity, or is it because the child("Users").child(KeyUser); doesnt exist in my DB and I have to create it in a prior activity

Comment: as i see in your database structure, you are doing right the reference, the value keyUser is returning null and thats the problem.