# How to solve "java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()"?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception

I don't understand where is my code going wrong

I tried some solutions but none of them are working in my case

**The code:**

```
package com.example.kiit.questionme2;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.kiit.questionme2.Model.User;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText;

public class Activity3 extends AppCompatActivity {

MaterialEditText edtnewpassword, edtnewemail, edtuser;//for signingup

FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference users;

Button signup;

public void goback(View view) {


    Intent intenta = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

    startActivity(intenta);

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_3);

    edtnewemail = (MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.newemail);
    edtnewpassword = (MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.newpassword);
    edtuser = (MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.newuser);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    users = database.getReference("Users");

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);
    signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signUp(edtnewemail.getText().toString(), edtnewpassword.getText().toString(), edtuser.getText().toString());
        }
    });


}

private void signUp(String emu, String pwd, final String use) {

    final User user = new User(edtuser.getText().toString());
    edtnewpassword.getText().toString();
    edtnewemail.getText().toString();

    users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.child(use).exists()) {
                if (!use.isEmpty()) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(use).exists())

                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Activity3.this, "User already exists.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else

                    {
                        users.child(user.getUsername())
                                .setValue(user);
                        Toast.makeText(Activity3.this, "User registration successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

**The error:**

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.kiit.questionme2, PID: 6946
java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.child(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.kiit.questionme2.Activity3$2.onDataChange(Activity3.java:76)
    at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpx.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZS(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Application terminated.
```

I need to take the username password and email as input and check if it exists, if yes show the appropriate message if not then registration successful with the data saved in Firebase.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child(); first time to firebase really confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49224752/java-lang-nullpointerexception-cant-pass-null-for-argument-pathstring-in-chi)

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371687/cant-pass-null-for-argument-pathstring-in-child

Answer (score 0):

instead of `if (dataSnapshot.child(use).exists())`,

try `if(use!=null && ! use.isEmpty() && dataSnapshot.child(use).exists()))`

Comment: I am so sorry I posted the wrong code. This is the code that has the error.

Answer (score 0):

This error/crash is due to the fact that `use` is null in the code where you are putting it, specifically at this line of code:

```java
dataSnapshot.child(use).exists()
```

So, what you can do is check if `use` is not null before calling this `signUp` method. This would ensure that you don't get null in your field in the code.

So the code for above approach would look something like this:

```java
if(use!=null){
  // call this method here
}
else {
 // do something else
}
```

This would ensure that your code does not catch `nullPointer` during the execution of the method, rather before the method gets executed. Hence a smoother flow in your app.

Comment: I am so sorry I posted the wrong code. This is the code that has the error.

Comment: @prernamitra which is line 76 in this code according to your IDE?

Comment: line 76 is just a blank space

Comment: Uhmm, what's the line above it, the code line nearest to 76?

Comment: 75                       if (dataSnapshot.child(use).exists())

Comment: Okay, so the problem is same, try the approach I've given in my answer.

Comment: Its not working. Is there some other place where I can contact you?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Can you tell and show what did you try for this, and if any new text is appearing in logcat?

Comment: if (!use.isEmpty()) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child(use).exists()) {

Comment: This would not check if `use` is null or not. It'd crash your app, at first if. You should read my answer and do according to it exactly.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.kiit.questionme2, PID: 6946
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.child(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.kiit.questionme2.Activity3$2.onDataChange(Activity3.java:76)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Unknown Source)

Comment: I saw your answer where do i have to add the null statement?

Comment: It is crashing. I really need to get this project completed today. If you could please tell me where exactly to put the check statement for use . i woiuld be extremely grateful